# Make more monadic solution

Tags: haskell

```
instance (Functor m) => Functor (MaybeT m) where
    fmap f m = MaybeT $ fmap (\x -> case x of
        Just j -> Just (f j)
        Nothing -> Nothing
        ) (runMaybeT m)
```

My implementation of `Functor MaybeT`. But, on my eye it seems to by a bit ugly ;) from monadic semantic / monadic solution. Please suggest me some advices to be better functional programmer :).

Comment: the inner case is just another `fmap` ;)

Comment: `fmap (\x -> case x of Just j -> Just (f j); Nothing -> Nothing) = fmap (\x -> fmap f x) = fmap (fmap f)`. The double `fmap` should be surprising since you have nested functors. You need one `fmap` for each layer.

Comment: @Bakuriu You surely mean "should _not_ be surprising" :)

Comment: @Bakuriu `= (fmap . fmap) f`

Comment: @NikitaVolkov iMO `fmap (fmap f)` is more readable as it indicates the nesting better

Comment: @chi Yeah, obviously. I believe I had written it, then I decided to rephrase the sentence and forgot it.

Comment: @Carsten Might be, but I find it rather eye-opening, as it provides a whole other perspective on the problem.